# A accurate tool for digitization in qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, digitizing

I have some raster maps that  need to be digitized.
Me problem is that some of the shapes are very hard to be digitized.
Take for example the circles that need to be digitized in this map

[image]
Now matter how accurate I will be the result will never a perfect shape.
 [image]

Is there some kind of plugin that provide better digitized tools for circles  or squares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into it and find a plugin that serve this purpose.
It's called "CADDigitize" [image]

The plugin give us the option to make some variations of squares and circels.
Once installed you need to crate a new layer and clikc on thre CADDigitize icon[image]
Now you can make circles, or other shapes, as a polygon or line layer[image]

It's also possible to add more shapes like squares, ellipse or arcs.
have not listed here [image]

Answer (score 3):

Just to add an additional option to this question, there is also a plugin called Rectangles Ovals Digitising which adds a quick toolbar allowing you to draw rectangles or ovals from either a corner or from the centre. It's less easily controllable than CAD Digitise but slightly easier if you don't need the high precision of CAD.

[image]